# ChromeDriver - error while loading shared libraries: libgfx.so

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, raspberry-pi, selenium-chromedriver

Cannot open ChromeDriver on raspberry pi 3 after successfully installed.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/InstaPy $/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver --version

/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgfx.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```